# copyItemAtPath works on simulator but fails on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsfilemanager

I have this code that copy a .txt file from main bundle to documents dir. This works on simulator but fails to work on Device. I verify that it works on Simulator by deleting the txt file in documents dir and running the app again. When I run the app on the Device, copyItemAtPath failed. here's my code.

```
     BOOL success;
     NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
     NSError *error;
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

     NSString *writableDBPath= [documentsDirectory  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"zipFileName.txt"];
     success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
     if (success)
     {
        return;
     }

     // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
     NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"zipFileName.txt"];
     success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
     if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.",   [error localizedDescription]);
     }
```

I tried cleaning and building again, i even restart the phone but nothing works.

**ERROR**: 2012-05-08 16:13:19.487 balita[162:707] *** Assertion failure in -[ViewController currentJsonFile], /Users/diffy/Documents/balita/balita/ViewController.m:144
2012-05-08 16:13:19.496 balita[162:707]**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to create writable database file with message 'The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)'.'
** First throw call stack:

Comment: what error message do you get from [error localizedDescription] ?

Comment: I've updated my question, attached the error message.

Comment: There is case sensitivity difference between device and simulator.  Device is case sensitive.

Comment: user523234 was correct. The filename I have is zipfileName.txt and I'm calling the file in my code as zipFileName.txt. It's ok now. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Foundation/FoundationErrors.h` gives you `NSFileReadNoSuchFileError = 260,                        // Read error (no such file)`

which means the file is not copied to the app bundle during the build any more.

The simulator bundle still has the file as the new files are copied there during the build but previously copied are not removed even while you perform the targets Clean.

To reproduce an issue with a simulator you can remove an app from there (either with a long tap or by removing the app folder from the simulator directory) and reinstalling it.

To fix the problem add the file to `Copy Bundle Resources` stage of your target and check that the file is added to the project and exists.